# Unable to get variable from secondary method if sending table explicitly from primary method

Tags: karate

I have a strange problem.

I have two files, one is my primary file and second one is secondary file that has a secondary method.

The primary file has a table and it calls the secondary file like this:

```
        * table names
            | id   | 
            |'123' | 
        * def getEmail = call read('emailFile.feature@idEmail') names
        * def getVariable = getEmail.address
        * karate.log(getVariable)
```

The secondary file has something like this:

```
    @idEmail
    Scenario: Get address and return it
        * input('#search', id)
        * def getAddress = (driver.value('#address')).trim()  
        * def address =  getAddress
```

Problem is: The karate.log(getVariable) line in the primary file does not return any value. However, if I remove "names" from the call read to the secondary file, it does return the value. My manager is insisting I send the table name explicitly to the secondary call to be "safe".

It may be something very obvious I am missing but I have tried other solutions and can't figure it out.

EDIT: Adding generic scenario below for local execution:

Primary file:

```
        Given driver 'https://google.com'
        * driver.maximize()
        * table searchText
            | searchInput| 
            | 'test'     | 
        * def callInput = call read('otherFile.feature@testInput')searchText
        * def getStuff = callInput.getText2
        * karate.log(getStuff)
```

The secondary file:

```
    @testInput
    Scenario: abc
        * input('#APjFqb', searchInput + Key.ENTER, 20)
        * def getText = (driver.text("div[class='VpH2eb vmod'] span[data-dobid='hdw']")).trim()
        * def getText2 = getText
        * karate.log(getText2)
```

EDIT FINAL:
I was able to resolve the issue by changing:

```
        * table names
            | id   | 
            |'123' | 
        * def getEmail = call read('emailFile.feature@idEmail') names
```

TO:

```
* def names = {id: '123'}
* def getEmail = call read('emailFile.feature@idEmail') names
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually "call arguments" are only needed when you want to specify data "inline". If you already have a variable "in scope", which is `names`, the design of Karate is such that it will always be "visible" to called features. So there is nothing "extra safe" in your case.

The mistake you are doing is very subtle, but explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read - see the second last row.

So please remove the space after `read` and do this:

```
* def getEmail = call read('emailFile.feature@idEmail') names
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Thomas. Sorry, I made a mistake in this question. In my actual script, I actually don't have a space between read and the parenthesis. I had an inkling that this "extra safe" route my manager keeps pushing was hogwash, given my experience with Karate. Anything else that could be causing the issue?

Comment: @hungryhippos unfortunately I can't spot anything else without an example I can run locally

Comment: okay I edited my post to add a generic scenario. Please take a look.

Comment: Ok I was able to resolve it by changing table to:

        * def searchText= {searchInput: 'test'}
        * def callInput = call read('otherFile.feature@testInput')searchText
        * def getStuff = callInput.getText2
        * karate.log(getStuff)

Could this be a bug?

Comment: @hungryhippos sorry I'm lost